# Hiding menu links after being authenticated Angular

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I'm currently involved in a project that is using Angular with a IdentityServer4 authentication service. Currently when the user first gets to our page we are showing a login link.  When the user clicks this link they are redirected to IdentityServer login page.  Upon successful login the user is redirected back to our service whereby new menu links are made available.

The problem is that there is a delay whereby the OidcSecurityService library that is being used can determine if we are authenticated or not.  During this delay
the Login link is still available until it is made to disappear when authentication is confirmed.

I have considered hiding the login by default and only showing however this link does need to be available when we are not logged in and the OidcSecurityService does
not have any methods available from what I can see that allows us to know whether the authentication check has been made.

Is there a recommended approach to having it so that the login link is not available at all on initial page display?

**HTML**

```
    <li routerLinkActive="active" class="hide"
        *ngIf="!userIsAuthorized"
        [ngClass]="{'show': showLogin, 'hide': !showLogin }">
      <a style="cursor:pointer;" (click)="onLogin()">Login</a>
    </li>
```

This service is activated from the OidcSecurityService layer when the authentication is determined.

**UserService**

```
constructor(private securityService: OidcSecurityService,
          private userApiService: UserApiService,
          private spinnerService: SpinnerService) {

console.log('userService() start');

    //this will allow us to get the user details, needed to get the user permissions
    this.securitySubscription = this.securityService.onUserDataLoaded
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('loading user data');

        this.userLoadStarted.next(true);
        this.loadAllUserDetails();
    });

    //We must check the local storage and IF user details saved, use these values and emit event, else make/use empty
    var userAuthorized = this.securityService.isAuthorized;

  if (userAuthorized != undefined && userAuthorized === true) {
    console.log('userService() isw auth');

    this.userPermissions = LocalStorageService.read('userPermissions');
    this.userDetails = LocalStorageService.read('userDetails');

    this.userDetailsAlreadyLoaded = true;
  } else {
    console.log('userService() not auth');

      this.userPermissions = [];
      this.userDetailsAlreadyLoaded = false;
    }

console.log('userService() end');
}
```

Comment: Throw us some example code. There's half a dozen ways to do this, but using pre-existing code we might be able to show you a quick clean way.

Comment: @Z.Bagley  The problem I find is that the Oidbc Service only triggers the load event of the user service which does the hide and show if it actually does the authentication.  So when the user is not logged in my update will never occur.  Hence I can't hide the Login by default cause I will never be able to show it. ......

Answer (score 0):

Using your current setup you'll want to add a loginClicked variable to your **UserService**. Also, it's better to either stick with `ngIf` *OR* `ngClass`, and `ngIf` is the more reliable method.

**HTML**

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="!userService.userIsAuthorized || !userService.loginClick"> <!-- Only show if the user isn't authorized or login hasn't been clicked -->
  <a style="cursor:pointer;" (click)="onLogin()">Login</a>
</li>
```

Main changes in the service will include the creation of a loginClicked variable to manage the state of the login process. You will want to include this at the top of your login API. Only the constructor was included in your code example, but I'll assume that your component `onLogin()` calls a function in this service to initialize login.

```
public userIsAuthorized = false;
public loginClick = false;

login() {
  // Your call to the login service here
  // ...
  // ...
  // This is also the area where you set userIsAuthorized to true on successful subscribe.

  this.loginClick = true;
}
```

I created [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bZCk8zzJuOEnwLCSaHxV?p=preview) that shows how this works.

Comment: A quick question.  When the login is clicked we are navigated away from the site to the identityserver login page.  When it's logged in we are redirected back to our site.  Will this method still work in that the loginClick will be remembered when it comes back to the site?

Comment: It will not. You will need cookies in order for that to work, or open in new page.